# How to get values from Sql server database in DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I want the data values from one table in datagridviewcomboboxcolumn and another value of 2nd table in datagridviewtextbox column on selecting datagridviewcomboboxcell

My code is below:

```
 Private Sub Populate()
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable

    con.Open()
    Dim Cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select * from Itemmaster where flag='G'", con)
    dt1.Load(Cmd1.ExecuteReader)
    Cmd1.CommandText = "Select * from Itemdetail"
    dt2.Load(Cmd1.ExecuteReader)


    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1

    Dim colpgCombo As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    colpgCombo.DataSource = dt1
    colpgCombo.DisplayMember = "Name"
    colpgCombo.ValueMember = "code"
    colpgCombo.DataPropertyName = "Name"
    colpgCombo.HeaderText = "Product Group"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colpgCombo)

    Dim colpru As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    colpru.DataPropertyName = "Unit"
    colpru.HeaderText = "Unit"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colpru)

    Dim colHsn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()


    colHsn.DataPropertyName = "Hsncode"
    colHsn.HeaderText = "Hsncode"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colHsn)

    Dim colRate As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    colRate.DataPropertyName = "Rate"
    colRate.HeaderText = "Rate"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colRate)

End Sub

Private Sub ButtonNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNewItem.Click
    Populate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Show the code you have tried and explain how it did not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Populate()
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable

    con.Open()
    Dim Cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select * from Itemmaster where flag='G'", con)
    dt1.Load(Cmd1.ExecuteReader)
    Cmd1.CommandText = "Select * from Itemdetail"
    dt2.Load(Cmd1.ExecuteReader)


    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt1

    Dim colpgCombo As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
    colpgCombo.DataSource = dt1
    colpgCombo.DisplayMember = "Name"
    colpgCombo.ValueMember = "code"
    colpgCombo.DataPropertyName = "Name"
    colpgCombo.HeaderText = "Product Group"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colpgCombo)

    Dim colpru As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    colpru.DataPropertyName = "Unit"
    colpru.HeaderText = "Unit"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colpru)

    Dim colHsn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()


    colHsn.DataPropertyName = "Hsncode"
    colHsn.HeaderText = "Hsncode"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colHsn)

    Dim colRate As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    colRate.DataPropertyName = "Rate"
    colRate.HeaderText = "Rate"
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(colRate)


End Sub
Private Sub ButtonNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonNewItem.Click
    Populate()
End Sub
```

Comment: kindly help me to get values in datagridcomboboxcolumn

Comment: What is this blob of code with no explanation?  Is it a clarification to your question?  Is it supposed to be an answer?

Comment: How to Get Values from Sql server Database in Datagridviewcomboboxcolumn and datagridviewtextboxcolumn, I found error with above mentioned codes